# Prove that there exists a long exact sequence...

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f, g : X \to Y$ be two continuous maps. Consider the space $Z$ which is obtained from the disjoint union of $Y$ with $(X \times [0, 1])$ by identifying $(x, 0) \sim f (x), (x, 1) \sim g(x),$ for each $x$ in $X$. Let $i$ denote the natural inclusion of $Y$ into $Z$. Prove that there exists a long exact sequence of the following form:
$$\cdots\longrightarrow H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(Y ) \xrightarrow{\;i_*\;} H_n(Z) \longrightarrow H_{n−1}(X) \longrightarrow\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

The  space $Z$ you construct is also called the *double mapping cylinder* $M(f,g)$. By cutting it in the middle, you can see it as the union of two mapping cylinders $M(f),M(g)$ identified at the ends $X \times \{0\}$.

[image: cyl]

Above is a simple rough (!) sketch. Now apply the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to this union.

A good example of this is to take the two maps $f,g: S^1 \to S^1$ given by $z\mapsto z^2, z \mapsto z^3$ respectively. The coequaliser of $f,g$, obtained by identifying $f(z) \sim g(z)$, is not even Hausdorff. But $M(f,g)$ is a nice CW-complex.

The fundamental group of this example is also of interest. It has two generators say $a,b$ and one relation $a^2=b^3$.